# AdMob Payment issue

Tags: admob

Last Day I saw a upgrade button in my AdMob Account and I hit that and upgraded.
After that I saw that the revenue is separate from my Old AdMob.
In the new AdMob Account all revenue is calculated separately.
And my apps doesn't show any impressions in the new admob account, but the revenue is updating.

My main question is

I have set "Payment Via Wire" in my old AdMob Account and still there is some money remaining there.
I read that new AdMob doesn't support Paypal or Wire, then how are they going to pay my amount remaining in the Old AdMob account?

Comment: I have same issue. Please let me know how to sort out this?

Answer (score 0):

The funds in your old account will be paid out via the payment method specified in the old interface.

You can also request a refund of your legacy AdMob advertising funds in [here](https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3098569).

For more details about your legacy account, see [this link](https://support.google.com/admob/v2/faq/3108470?hl=en#3131214).

And [this link](https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3029594?hl=en) is how you import your legacy data to new account.

Comment: I can't login to the old interface without updating it now. Can I still get paid via the old payment method?